# mongodb aggregation for calculating attendance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that has a document with the following value

```
{
 "_id": ObjectID("XXXXXX"),
 "more details" :more details
 "attendance": [
    {
        "date": ISODate("2015-08-11T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "students": [
            {
                "studentId": ObjectID("YYYYYY"),
                "entryTime": ISODate("1970-01-01T05:41:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1970-01-01T05:41:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            },
            {
                "studentId": ObjectID("ZZZZZZ"),
                "entryTime": ISODate("1970-01-01T06:42:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1970-01-01T06:42:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": ISODate("2015-08-12T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "students": [
            {
                "studentId": ObjectID("XXXXX"),
                "entryTime": ISODate("1970-01-01T05:41:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1970-01-01T06:42:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            },
            {
                "studentId": ObjectID("YYYYY"),
                "entryTime": ISODate("1970-01-01T05:41:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1970-01-01T06:42:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Absent"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get the number of days a student has been present and the number of days that he has been absent. But i keep getting the output as undefined.

```
var pipeline = [
            {
                "$match": {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(batchId)}
            },
            {
                "$project": {attendance: '$attendance.students'}
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "studentId": "$studentId"
                    ,
                    "Present": {
                        "$sum": {
                            "$cond": [{"$eq": ["attendanceStatus", "Present"]}, 1, 0]
                        }
                    },
                    "Absent": {
                        "$sum": {
                            "$cond": [{"$eq": ["attendanceStatus", "Absent"]}, 1, 0]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ];
```

Am unable to figure out what I am missing out on

Comment: Just as a mention, there is clearly something horribly wrong with the code that is recording this data or the data conversion job or whatever it was. Though there is a main date i.e `ISODate("2015-08-11T18:30:00.000Z")` on the outer array, each item within appears only to have the "hours" added to the epoch date `ISODate("1970-01-01T05:41:00.000Z")` rather than added to the base date where they likely should be `ISODate("2015-08-11T05:41:00.000Z")`. So you might look at that before it comes back eventually to bite you. Also if you are using MongoDB 3.2 then there is a much more efficient way.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, Thanks for the info, I see your point, the input type "time" sets it to 1970 by default. Will look into it, thanks a ton. We are going to migrate to 3.2, any pointers on what I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this pipeline

```
var pipeline = [{$unwind: '$attendance'}, 
                {$unwind: '$attendance.students'}, 
                {$group: {
                    _id: '$attendance.students.studentId', 
                    "Present": {
                        "$sum": {
                            "$cond": [
                                 {"$eq": ["$attendance.students.attendanceStatus", "Present"]},
                                  1, 
                                  0]
                        }
                     },
                     "Absent": {
                        "$sum": {
                            "$cond": [
                                 {"$eq": ["$attendance.students.attendanceStatus", "Absent"]},
                                   1,
                                   0]
                        }
                    }}}]
```